# Secure hash function into $\mathbb{Z}_q$

Tags: hash

Given the existence of a secure hash function $h: \{ 0,1 \}^* \rightarrow \{0,1\}^k$, how can I construct a secure hash function $h': \{ 0,1 \}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_q$ ?

Of course this is easy for $q=2^k$, as we can always see $\{ 0,1 \}^k$ as the set $\mathbb{Z}_{2^k}$, but what if $q$ is an arbitrary integer?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does [this Q&A](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/37305/23623) answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

You can define $ h' $ as $ h'(m) := h(m) \mod q $.

As long as $ 2^k $ is larger than $ q $ by e.g. 128 bits, the resulting function $ h' $ is (almost) equally distributed in $ \mathbb Z_q $.

For a suitable hashfunction $ h $ you might pick a SHA-3 with variable output size, like SHAKE256.

Comment: I think we discussed something similar before. If you want a well distributed result you can use the output of SHAKE256 as input for a function that extract such numbers from a bit stream, the simplest being compare and redo if too large (this is of course non-deterministic, which can be an issue as you don't know the required output size of SHAKE256 in advance).

Comment: Well the error is extremely small when compared to the ideal distribution, as long $ 2^k $ is significately larger than $ q $ (e.g. $k=2176$ for a 2048 bit value of $ q $).